# Prevent a specific binary program from listening on specific IP?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

I have a two interfaces sets on my Raspberry Pi 3, each one with its own IP.

There's this binary (DeCONZ REST API) that when started will automatically expose a web server on both the IPs on the port `80`.
It doesn't expose any configuration to tell it which IP to use so I was wondering if there's any way at system level to block the binary from using one of those IPs?

Comment: Do you need to actually stop it from opening the listening socket on that IP (e.g., because you need something else to listen on port 80 there) or just stop it from getting connections there (e.g., because you only want it reachable from the LAN, not WAN)?

Comment: I need to run something else on the other ip on port 80

Comment: applications are usually responsible for those system calls. I guess you could maybe LD_PRELOAD it as a kluge, maybe?

Comment: Mind to give more detailed instructions in an answer please?

Comment: I would guess you could use seccomp as well. Or network namespaces. Both of those are going to be ... complicated. I presume the binary is running as root, otherwise it wouldn't be able to listen on 80 at all...

Comment: No it's running on a normal user, I added the capability to make it run on 80

Comment: The easy fix would be... what happens if you start the other thing first? It should get a can't bind, already in use error. Does it just give up and exit? (In which case, it'd likely do the same with permission denied).

Comment: Actually that's what I'm trying right now, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Not really a good answer for the general question, but for your specific case — that appears to be open source, and it'd be trivial to change https://github.com/dresden-elektronik/deconz-rest-plugin/blob/690a70e8332b121a8027620bf9cc753bf99f8cdd/websocket_server.cpp#L30 to be the IP you want it to listen on.

Comment: I don't have any experience with cpp, I opened an issue hoping they fix it :-(

Comment: I'd guess changing `QHostAddress::AnyIPv4` to `QHostAddress("192.168.0.1")` would work. But I haven't even tested if that'll compile. OTOH, it looks like it'll just ignore failures, so making sure to start the other program first should work.

Comment: I tried to start the other program first but it doesn't seem to work then

Comment: I thought the question was about distinction binary/scripts in general, in preventing the one from listening, so I edited the title, slightly.

Comment: @userunknown I think it is about in general too, or at least that'll make it the most useful to future visitors — that's why I didn't consider my workaround an answer...

Comment: @derobert: I guess my comment was unclear. It wasn't pointed to any comment, but to the reason, I edited the title. I read the headline on the question page and my first idea was: No, it's not possible, to prevent binary programs to listen on an IP, but to allow all scripts, because scripts are interpreted by binary programs or other scripts, which are. So in the end it is always a binary program. Reading the question, it cleared up. The question is about, how to prevent a specific program to access the web via IP/Port. The method should, of course, address such individual programs in general.

Comment: The next version of DeCONZ will support to specify the IP :-)